# Aggregating Polygon Data in a Buffer in R

Tags: r, polygon

I have an excel file with gas stations and another shape file that has polygons (counties) and the corresponding population per county.

I've converted the excel file into a geospatial one using the st_as_sf command. The county shape file has polygons of all counties in the city and per county has a column which indicates the population in the county.

I was able to create a buffer around the gas stations and using map view able to plot the county, buffer and gas station together.

My question is how many person live within x meters (my buffer) from this gas station. In the picture the blue areas are the buffers around the gas station and the layer below shows the different counties coloured by "Population". Searching around has focused on counting points in a polygon but my query is a bit different.

I essentially want to pull from the population column in my county shape file and say 400 ppl live in the buffer of gas station 1 etc etc..for all gas stations.

[picture of gas stations and buffers in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOUlx.jpg)

#create a buffer around fuel stations 1000 metres

```
petrol_buffer <- st_buffer(stations_geo,1000) %>% 
    rename(fuel_station_buffer=geometry) %>% 
     st_as_sf() %>% 
      mutate(buffer_id =1:29)
```

#create centroids of communities so that i can see which centroids fall within the fuel station buffer

```
   population_geo <- population_geo %>% 
    mutate(centroids= st_centroid(geometry))
```

#determine which centroids fall into fuel station buffers

```
in_buffer<-    st_intersection(population_geo$centroids,  petrol_buffer$fuel_station_buffer) %>% 
 as_tibble() %>% 
 rename(in_buffer_geo=geometry) %>% 
  st_as_sf(  crs = 4326) 

  in_buffer <- in_buffer %>% 
    st_join(population_geo, by='centroids')
```

#this is where im stuck i need to find a way to link this back to my fuel station file so i can know which fuel stations are being referenced by the 196 communities

Comment: Assuming proportional distribution of the population I would suggest to use `st_area()` function to calculate the area of polygons, divide the population by the polygon area (to have population density) and multiply by `st_area(buffer(...))` of your buffer. If the buffer overlaps several polygons, then you have to find `st_area(st_intersection(...))` of buffer/polygons, multiply by individual population density and summarize it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzSapijaszko. Sadly each polygon has a different population but the .shp file does have population and area of each polygon/county. How do I add data to this post though so that you can review better ?

Comment: @ianaj, please check my answer below. Instead of `shapefile` I have used census data and created two randomly buffers (which corresponds to your gas stations)

Answer (score 0):

In example below I will use `tigris` package to get county geometries (instead of shapefile) and create few buffers (as gas station). Please note, that population density is an example, not real one.

```r
library(tigris)
library(sf)
LA <- counties(state = "LA", cb = TRUE)
LA <- LA |>
  mutate(area = as.double(st_area(geometry)/10^6)) |>
  mutate(density = 200000/area) |>
  st_as_sf()
plot(LA["density"])
```

[image]

Let's create sample buffers -- in our case just two, for simplicity:

```r
buffers <- st_sample(LA, 2) |>
  st_buffer(dist = 50000) |>
  st_as_sf() |>
  mutate(ID = 1:2)
  
plot(buffers$x, lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Now, we have to find those counties (and their parts) which intersects with our buffers. The easiest way is just call `st_intersection()` function which in this case works like filter and returns the list of geometries, then we have to calculate the area/number of people and summarize it by our buffer ID.

```r
LA |>
 st_intersection(buffers) |>
  mutate(aa = as.double(st_area(geometry)/10^6)) |>
  mutate(how_many_peple = aa * density) |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  summarise(sum(how_many_peple))

Simple feature collection with 2 features and 2 fields
[...]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ID `sum(how_many_peple)`                                                                                     geometry
  <int>                 <dbl>                                                                                <POLYGON [°]>
1     1               823361. ((-91.95035 30.28296, -91.94902 30.28298, -91.94413 30.28305, -91.94413 30.28882, -91.939...
2     2               292827. ((-93.29358 30.05181, -93.29358 30.05433, -93.28855 30.05446, -93.28855 30.05734, -93.286...
```

Please note area is in `km^2` and density in `number of people/km^2`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was able to run your code. But in my use case I got an error message. The code that im running uses 'st_intersection' to create buffers around my gas stations. There are 196 centroids (of counties) in the buffer zone of my 29 gas stations. Im trying to group the buffers by station but it won't work, I get the error message "buffer must be 196 or 1". I need to connect centroids to a gas station.  Essentially my 196 communities are can be grouped by my 29 buffers but I can't fig out how..

Comment: Would you mind to share `.shp` and excel data somehow? And your current code, please?

Comment: Thanks please let me know how. Ive edited the post to show some of the code so you have a better sense as to where I am.

Comment: But what are centroids for? If you have to calculate the population within buffer, then you have to find area of the communities which intersects with buffer.

Comment: The centroids are of the communities/counties.  My population .shp file has the (there are 500), population, area  and centroid of each community. As described above I was able (using st_intersections) to make a new df of all the communities (196/500) within my fuel station buffer. I then, using st_join gathered some info (i.e. pop & area) from my pop df into this new df with 196 rows.  In this new df I don't know which centroids belong to which fuel station buffer.  I would like to link each of the 196 centroids to a fuel station buffer.

Comment: You can check if their intersects with station buffers using `st_intersects(buffer, centroid, sparse = TRUE )` - it returns TRUE/FALSE for each buffer/centroid combination.

Comment: Thanks. So the most bizarre thing occurred. I ran your suggestion and it worked brilliantly I got a list  which I converted to a data frame (196 rows i.e only where buffer and centroid intersected). That df had the row and column id where the intersection occurred allowing me to determine which buffer covered which centroid. I took a break and came back to my commuter. Now the code doesn't work.  Its now creating a list of my centroids multiplied by my buffers so that now I get 15,863 rows i.e. (547 centroids times my 29 fuel stations)....

Comment: Figured out the issue. I ve gotten the file to work. Essentially the st_intersection can only be used once. Running the code a second time causes the variables to interact hence then (547*29).  Thanks again for your help.